# Checking if table exists and has default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I make the below 2 checking  in one select ? I am checking first if table exists then i am checking if it has default value.

Can I check in one select if table exists and has default value ?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM syscolumns c WHERE c.id = OBJECT_ID('EX_EMPLOYEE') 
AND c.name = 'B_TIME')
begin
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.all_columns c join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
join sys.default_constraints d on c.default_object_id = d.object_id
where t.name = 'EX_EMPLOYEE' and c.name = 'B_TIME')
        BEGIN
        EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE EX_EMPLOYEE ADD  DEFAULT 1 for B_TIME')
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: what you mean by default value?

Comment: @Coder1991 you can give default values to each column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to check both the conditions in one if clause then you can do it as  below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM syscolumns c WHERE c.id = OBJECT_ID('EX_EMPLOYEE') 
AND c.name = 'B_TIME')
and NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.all_columns c join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
join sys.default_constraints d on c.default_object_id = d.object_id
where t.name = 'EX_EMPLOYEE' and c.name = 'B_TIME')

begin
....
end
```