# SELECT if table exists in WITH clause (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating a table to keep **continuous login days** which are the results of the combination of `login_[today]` and `continuous_login_[previous_day]`. However, I want to handle the exception if the table for `[previous_day]` doesn't exist.

With the help of the references [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859614/bigquery-check-if-table-exists-or-not), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45367895/checking-if-table-exists-and-has-default-values), and [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015307/sql-server-if-exists-then-1-else-2/41015373), I was able to retrieve the value (continuous logins) only if the table for the previous day exists like **`A`**.

However, I wasn't able to use the result of `IF EXISTS` statement inside `WITH` clause like **`B`**. How can I use the results of the `IF EXISTS` in `WTIH` clause. Or is there any better way of doing this work?

A.

```sql
-- Retrieve only if the table exists
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM `my_project.my_dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
        WHERE table_id = CONCAT('_my_table_', '20201010')  -- daily log
    )
THEN
    (
        SELECT
            pid, MAX(continuous_login_days) AS continuous_login_days
        FROM `my_project.my_dataset._my_table_*`
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20201010'
        GROUP BY pid
    );
ELSE
    SELECT NULL;
END IF
```

B.

```
-- GOAL
WITH
...
, continuous_logins_table AS (
    [above statement]
)
SELECT
    ...
    IFNULL(continuous_logins_table.continuous_login_days, 0) + 1 AS continuous_login_days,
FROM
    ...
    LEFT JOIN continuous_logins_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  pid, MAX(continuous_login_days) AS continuous_login_days
  FROM `my_project.my_dataset._my_table_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20201010'
  AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM `my_project.my_dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
    WHERE table_id = CONCAT('_my_table_', '20201010')
  )
GROUP BY pid
```